# Concatenating a string to files discovered with "find"

Tags: bash, find, printf

In a for loop, I am finding image files that match a certain name and then creating a text file of these image files (the text file gets updated every time a new image file is added in the for loop).

```
find ~/grads_pics/${MODEL}/${INIT_INTDATE}/${INITHOUR}z/ -type f -name "${FILENAMES[i]}${FORECASTHOUR}hrfcst.png" -printf '%f\n' >> ~/grads_pics/${MODEL}/${INIT_INTDATE}/${INITHOUR}z/${FILENAMES[i]}".txt"
```

I would like to concatenate some text before these file names... ex: sometext${FILENAMES[i]}${FORECASTHOUR}hrfcst.png, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I tried putting '%s\n' $MYSTRING after '%f\n' in the code above but the command didn't produce any output, so it must be incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find's `-printf` option isn't the same as C's printf function.
Following man page : `man find`

```
%s : File's size in bytes.
```

What about adding your string replacing `%` by `%%` before %f

```
... -printf "${your_var//%/%%}"'%f\n'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to get that to work - I'm sure it is an error on my side as I am very new to programming though. Did you mean for me to put -printf "${MYSTRING//%/%%}" '%f\n' ,where MYSTRING is the string I am trying to add to the beginning of the filename found by find?

Comment: yes but pay attention to spaces which are argument delimiters in shell, there is no space between "${MYSTRING//%/%%}" and '%f\n'

Comment: Yup that fixed it! Thank you.